# Good portable 5V 1.5A power source

Tags: power-supply, batteries, usb, portable

I'm a computer science student who is trying to make a portal augmented reality version of the [Oculus](http://www.oculusvr.com/).

I'm looking for a power source that will is both portable and able to deliver 5V at 1.5A for an extended duration (at least 2 hours). Is this reasonable and where would I be able to find such a power source (I'm in the Netherlands)? I looked online and it said that you can use a USB port to provide 5V, however it warned not to go beyond 0.5A which is not enough for the Oculus (I do hope I went to the right site if not please tell me which one would be correct).

As I will be depleting this battery regularly it would be nice if it was rechargeable. 
In this case, portable means a weight limit in the order of 0.5 kg and a size limit mainly in dept of no deeper than 5 cm, longer than 20 cm, or wider then 15 cm.

Comment: Have you found a battery that might  be able to provide the power but maybe has the wrong voltage - you'll probably need something that is rated at 4Ah (4000 mAh) and greater than 6V at the end of its energy cycle i.e. before it needs a recharge - if you can find a battery that fits the bill then this halves the problem.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Here's an example of a battery that partly fits the bill: -

[image]

Take a look at this - dimensions are 100 x 70 x 45mm and you require 200 x 150 x 50.

However, it weighs 1kg and not 500g

Cost is quite cheap but, it still needs a regulator to provide the power output. This is the sort of thing you need to decide on - cost versus requirements. The extra regulator circuitry would probably cost less than £5 from eBay by the way.

Answer (score 0):

There are plenty of portable battery packs [like this](http://rads.stackoverflow.com/amzn/click/B00BQ5KHJW) available.

The one from the link supplies 5V @2A on one of its USB ports and has a capacity of 13000mAh. So battery life for 1.5A load is about 13000mAh/1500mA = 8.6h.

However, I would take all those parameters with a grain of salt. It will probably not supply the claimed 2A but somewhat lower and capacity will probably be much below the 13000mAh. But for your application it should suffice.

Answer (score 0):

You might want to consider using a standard DSLR Li battery and charger.

A Nikon EN-EL18 would supply 5V at 1.5A for more than 2 hours using an 80% efficient buck regulator, and weighs only 160g.

[image]

They also sell a dual charger MH-26 for it. Not particularly cheap, though.

Li batteries (particularly knock-off unbranded ones) may have a tendency to burst into flames, and air shipments are now [heavily](http://www.iata.org/whatwedo/cargo/dgr/Documents/Lithium-Battery-Packing-Instructions-965-970-EN.pdf) [restricted](http://www.iata.org/whatwedo/cargo/dgr/Documents/Lithium-Battery-Guidance-2014.pdf), so be careful about safety.